# Why am I getting an IndexOutOfRangeException here?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I can't figure out why I'm getting it in the `Where` clause below.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes consecutive characters,
    /// e.g. "aaabcc" --> "abc"
    /// </summary>
    public static void RemoveDuplicates(this string s)
    {
        var arr = s.ToCharArray()
                   .Where((i,c) => (i > 0) ? (c != s[i - 1]) : true)
                   .ToArray();
        s = new string(arr);

    }
}


public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "aaabcc";
        str.RemoveDuplicates();
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Also, is there a way to make this slightly more efficient and compact while still using LINQ?

Comment: I think it's the other way around, the first element is the char and the 2nd is the index. So switch `(i,c) to (c,i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Probably need to read the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) before using a Method or a special overload:

> Type: `System.Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>`
>
> A function to test each source element for a condition; the **second**
> parameter of the function represents the index of the source element

So your code should be something like this:

```
.Where((item, index) => (index > 0) ? (item != s[index - 1]) : true)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the wrong order of parameters here:

```
.Where((i, c) => (i > 0) ? (c != s[i - 1]) : true)
```

should become:

```
.Where((c, i) => (i > 0) ? (c != s[i - 1]) : true)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is the (i,c ) in your where.

You are using the following Enumerable extension [(See MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
```

Note that the index in the Func is the **second** parameter.

I think the fastest method would not be using linq, but would be a string extension:

```
public static string RemoveDuplicates(this string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return String.Empty(); // optional: return null

    var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    resultBuilder.Append(s.First());
    for (int i=1; i< s.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] != s[i-1])
            resultBuilder.Append(s[i]);
    }
    return resultBuilder.ToString();
}
```

However, if you really want to use linq, for instance because you want to append other linq statements you can mimic the above behaviour as follows, while still using lazy loading:

```
public static string RemoveDuplicates(this string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return String.Empty();
    s.AsEnumerable().Take(1)
        .Concat(s.AsEnumerable().Skip(1)
            .where( (c, i) => c != s[i]));
}
```

- Note that because of the check that string is not null, I am certain there is a First().
- Because of the Skip(1), index 0 in the where statement equals s[1], and index i equals s[i-1] for i>0.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) method already instead of your own method for this purpose:

```
var str = "aaabcca";
var result = string.Join("",str.ToCharArray().Distinct());
```

Result:

> "abc"

Edit:If you want to remove sequential duplicates you could try this code instead:

```
var removesequential = string.Join("",str.Where((c, i) => i == 0 || c != str[i - 1]));
```

Result:

> "abca"

Comment: Though `Distinct` does something different, his code tries to remove sequential duplicates, but distinct is global duplicates.